# how to implement two associations between two tables in mysql

Tags: java, mysql, sql, uml

Let's suppose this following scenario:

- A person can have one or many addresses:(1..*).
- An address is associated with 1 person:(1..1).
- A person have a home address & a work address

let's also suppose that we have a bidirectional associations (idk how to do this in power designer so excuse the following picture)

[image: UML diagram for this scenario]

Person table: id(pk),firstName,lastName

Address table: id(pk), streetName,locationNumber,city,country,id_Person(FK).

What should I add to this structure to correctly implement the work@,home@ associations to my tables.

Comment: two obvious scenarios are possible: either I add isHome,isWork column to address table, or I use two separate tables one to store home addresses and the other for work addresses. I'm wondering which one is better and is there any better way to do this ?

Comment: a person should have only one work and one home address or could have, say, 3 home address and zero work address?

Comment: a person should have 1 or more for each address: 3 home address(which represent all his previous/current addresses) + 1 work address at least

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i think you should go for the additional char not null column in addres table:
Unless you got more info to store differently between home or work address i dont see any reason to use two separate table.

Moreover we are talking about single select versus select double join just to retrieve a type information.

Answer (score 1):

Implement a table `PersonAdress` with two foreign keys to `Person` and `Address` plus a flag `HomeWork`.